# Парсинг из статьи в группе VK

Tags: javascript, парсер, vkontakte-api, api, вконтакте

Как можно реализовать парсинг из статьи в группе ВК? Через АПИ не выйдет ибо ВК не разработали АПИ под эти цели, через виджет для статей тоже не вариант ибо их нельзя стилизовать. Может есть ещё какие-то способы?

Comment: Ну можно, собственно, парсить)

Comment: Интересно бы как, если ещё не сделали метод под статьи

Comment: Ручками. Берем и парсим html.